# Como repetir uma consulta ajax que deu erro?

Tags: jquery, ajax

O problema é que às vezes a consulta esgota o tempo ou dá erro mesmo, então quero automatizar nesses casos.

```js
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'inserindodados.prisma',
            data: $('#FormularioDescoberta').serializeArray(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(sucesso){
            // Beleza deu certo!
            }
            error: function(erro){
            // Tente novamente
            }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloca uma função à volta para se poder auto-invocar.

Fiz um exemplo onde espera 0.5 segundos antes da proxima tentativa e recebe um máximo de tentativas.

Podes fazer a coisa mais avançada com `setTimeout` para interromper caso demore tempo demais, mas no exemplo considerei apenas o caso de chamar a callback de erro.

Exemplo:

```js
function ajax(dados, nrTentativas, cb) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'inserindodados.prisma',
    data: dados,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(sucesso) {
      // Beleza deu certo!
      cb(null, sucesso);
    }
    error: function(erro) {
      // Tente novamente
      if (nrTentativas > 0) setTimeout(ajax.bind(null, dados, nrTentativas - 1, cb), 500);
      else cb(erro);
    }

  });
}

var dados = $('#FormularioDescoberta').serializeArray();
ajax(dados, 5, function(err, resposta) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(resposta);
});
```

Comment: O que seria `bind(null` ?

Comment: @RafaelLemos o bind cria uma nova função já "configurada". O primeiro argumento indica o que será o `this` dentro dessa nova função. Os outros são os parametros da função quando for invocada. Como não preciso de usar o `this` coloquei `null`, mas podes usar outra coisa se quiseres.